# Restore subsite Home.aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

Would it be possible to reset a Subsite home.aspx page back to default configuration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible by doing the following:

- Open your subsite, Navigate to http://subsiteURL/_layouts/15/reghost.aspx
- `Reset Page to Site Definition Version` page should be open
- Check `Reset specific page to site definition version`, add your URL page, click Reset.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried it but getting this error message:     Sorry, something went wrong 
Cannot revert to the site definition version of this file. It is a custom file and is not part of the site definition. 
Technical Details 



Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: 34a10c9e-e9f8-c0f0-f89c-92f26f6c010b 

Date and Time: 8/6/2017 10:15:21 AM

Comment: do you create this  page or it's the default one?

Comment: This is a default subsite page. I have made changes to the text layout and color theme. Some where along the changes that I have made, it created extra text layout column that I cannot delete or edit. Therefore, I have trying to change it back to the default if possible without recreating the subsite.